# Unnatural join in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Input tables:

**EMP**

```
EMPNO   ENAME   DEPTNO  SAL DOJ
100 abc 10  1000    09-Jul-2007
200 def 20  2000    09-Jul-2014
300 ghi 30  3000    09-Jul-2009
400 jkl 40  4000    09-Jul-2010
500 mno 20  5000    09-Jul-2011
600 pqr 30  6000    09-Jul-2012
```

**Dept**

```
DEPTNO  DNAME   LOC
10      X       BZA
20      Y       MTM
30      Z       HYB
```

**sal**

```
SALGRADE    LL  HL
A          100  1000
B          1001 2000
C          2001 3000
D          3001 4000
E          4001 6000
```

Output:

```
EMPNO   ENAME   DEPTNO  SAL DOJ         DNAME   LOC SALGRADE
100     abc     10     1000 09-Jul-2007 X       BZA   A
200     def     20     2000 09-Jul-2014 Y       MTM   B
300     ghi     30     3000 09-Jul-2009 Z       HYB   C
500     mno     20     5000 09-Jul-2011 Y       MTM   E
```

Write a sql query to show output table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try following ways

First Way

```
 select top(4)*,(select salgrade from sal where emp.sal >= sal.LL  and emp.sal<= sal.HL) as salgrade
    from emp 
    inner join dept on emp.deptno=dept.deptno
    order by empno
```

Second Way

```
select top(4)*
         ,(select salgrade from sal where emp.sal between sal.LL and sal.HL) as salgrade
from emp
inner join dept on emp.deptno=dept.deptno
order by empno
```

Comment: Can we use a function like select top(4)*?? when we want to select top  rows...???